# Can CMake require static libraries (e.g., ZLIB)?

Tags: c++, static, cmake, zlib

It has been years since I worked in `C++`, and I've never used `CMake` before. I'm trying to compile a program called [ngmlr](https://github.com/philres/ngmlr), which uses `CMake`. It worked seamlessly on other systems I tried to build it on. This time around, `CMake` finds `ZLIB` (`Found ZLIB: /usr/lib64/libz.so (found version "1.2.3")`), as required by `ngmlr`, but the subsequent `make` fails with `ld: cannot find -lz`.

I *think* I know what's happening: `CMake` found the dynamic `ZLIB` library  (`libz.so`), but the `CMakeLists.txt` file requires `static` (I found the following option in the file: `option(STATIC "Build static binary" ON)`). As far as I can tell, the static library (`libz.a`) is missing on this machine. It's not in the same `/usr/lib64` directory as `libz.so`. `locate` is not available.

Questions:

1. Does that seem correct?
2. For education, assuming this is the problem, can you force `CMake` to look specifically for `static` `ZLIB`? e.g., since the developer required `static`, it would have been nice to immediately know the missing `static` library was the problem, rather than the embarrassingly long amount of time it took me to figure it out.

I've looked extensively for a clear answer to both, but didn't find anything conclusive (e.g., [Force cmake to use static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891290/force-cmake-to-use-static-libraries)).

**UPDATE**
I did confirm that the problem is that `ld` could not find the static library. Now I'm particularly interested to know if the developer can tell `CMake` to throw an error if the `static` libraries are not present, and save someone else.

`cmake version 2.8.8`

Comment: I would appreciate any feedback on how I can improve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Generally speaking it is up to Find-module authors. Some modules have special "static" option, others do not. Particularly [Zlib](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindZLIB.html) module has not. That's why cmake global variable is set in subdirectory `src/CMakeLists.txt`: `SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")`. But it is invoked after `find_package( ZLIB REQUIRED )` command. Looks like a bug.

> Now I'm particularly interested to know if the developer can tell CMake to throw an error if the static libraries are not present, and save someone else.

`REQUIRED` means that error will be thrown if package was not found. In your case it should be thrown if you move `SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` before `find_package`

Perhaps you can build your project if disable `STATIC` option

```
cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" _PATH_ -DSTATIC=OFF
```

Comment: Yes, I moved `SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")` to just before `find_package( ZLIB REQUIRED )` and that throws the appropriate error! I was able to finish building the project by disabling static.

Comment: I was able to get the static version by doing this, in case this helps anyone else: 

`set(_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})` `set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES "static.lib")` 

`find_package(ZLIB ${ZLIB_VERSION} REQUIRED MODULE)`

`set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})`
`unset(_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES)`

Comment: @GenericAccountName That should really have been written as an answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there was already an accepted answer and I wasn't sure if it would be helpful, but I'm happy to add it as an answer as well. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no cmake expert, but in case this helps anyone. I had found setting `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` successfully loaded the static lib, but I only wanted this for finding ZLIB, so I saved the previous value, set `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` and reset it like so:

```
set(_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES "static.lib") 
find_package(ZLIB ${ZLIB_VERSION} REQUIRED MODULE) 
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}) 
unset(_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES)
```

Answer (score -2):

Your `CMakeLists.txt` probably has this somewhere:

```
find_library(ZLIB z)
```

You can replace it with:

```
find_library(ZLIB libz.a)
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I'm not sure if I did something wrong, but that doesn't seem to work. The existing call is `find_package( ZLIB REQUIRED )`. I tried `find_package( ZLIB REQUIRED libz.a )`, but I still see get the following result: `Found ZLIB: /usr/lib64/libz.so (found version "1.2.3")`. I also tried changing `find_package` to `find_library`, but that doesn't appear to find `zlib` at all (nor does CMake throw an error). I do get undefined compiler errors for `zlib` functions (e.g., `gzopen`).